# jquery not working on appended content (after infinite scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i have a jquery function that displays a hidden content on each element in the loop of elements. This work perfectly, but the problem is that when i append new elements to the loop it stops working. It actually works on some elements and doesn't work on others (strange behavior).

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $(".see_all").click(function(){

  if ($(this).next().css('display') == 'none'){
  $(this).next().show();

  }
  else

  if($(this).next().is(':visible')){
  $(this).next().hide();
  }

  });
  })
  </script>
```

Html CODE

```
   <div class="center_container">
   <%for users in @user%>
   <div class="see_all">

   <span style="color:#808080;cursor:pointer">See All Reviews(<%=@beep_count=           (@beep.opposes.count +  @beep.neutrals.count + @beep.supports.count)%>)</span>

   </div>

   <div style="display:none;" class="hidden">

    No reviews available 

    </div>
   <%end%>

   </div>
```

i have tried solving it with this

```
   $("body").on("click", ".see_all", function() { 
   if ($(this).next().css('display') ==   'none')
    { 
    $(this).next().show(); 
    } 
    else 
    if($(this).next().is(':visible'))
    {                    
    $(this).next().hide(); 
    } 
    });
```

but it didn't work. am i making a mistake in my new jquery solution :(

**PLEASE HELP**

Comment: are you getting any kind of error in console?

Comment: And why not just `$(".see_all").on("click", function() {`

Comment: " (".see_all").on("click", function() { " doesn't work :(....any other suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED....i found out that i had compatibility problem with my jquery file